# Transfer Form-based data to java-script variables

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am building a Sharepoint hosted App. Is it possible to transfer Form-based data in java-script variables?

I tried something like this :

```
var MYform = "<form method='get' id='InputForm' action ='processForm'><table border=0><tr><td>Name</td><td><input type='text' id='Name' size=50 /></td></tr><tr><td>Description</td><td><textarea id='Description' rows=4 cols=51 /></td></tr><tr><td></td><td align='right'><br /><br /><input type='submit' id='siteSave' value='Save' /><input type='button' id='siteCancel' value='Cancel' /></td></tr></table></form>";

$('#message').html(MYform);

function processForm() {
   var UserName01 = request.getParameter("Name");
   var UserDescription01 = request.getParameter("Description");
}
```

Form display and input are working. But `function processForm()` is not executed and I don't know how to transfer the user-data into the variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I put the function in a different script (.js), the function can successfully found.

Comment: I can understand and I would love do that. I discovered this solution experimentally but I can't figure out why it is like that. I thought I share it anyways.